# How to prove that $\int_0^1 \frac{x^{1-p}(1-x)^pdx}{x^2+1}=\frac{\pi}{\sin px}(2^{\frac{p}{2}}\cos {\frac{p\pi}{4}}-1)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, beta-function

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^{1-p}(1-x)^pdx}{x^2+1}=\frac{\pi}{\sin px}(2^{\frac{p}{2}}\cos {\frac{p\pi}{4}}-1),(-1<p<2)$$

I don't know how to start. It's a beautiful integral, can someone help me,and any hint or trick will be appreciated.

Comment: Write $I$ for the integral and apply the substitution $x\mapsto 1/x$ to obtain $$I=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{(x-1)^p}{x(x^2+1)}\,dx$$ You can compute this via Cauchy integration formula applied to the keyhold contour.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you very much for your hint,but I still don't understand what is Cauchy integration formula and the keyhold contour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{x^2+1}\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^p\,dx = \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{(x-1)^p}{x(x^2+1)}\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^p}{(x+1)(x^2+2x+2)}\,dx$$
since $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{(x+1)(x^2+2x+2)}\right)=e^{-s}(1-\cos s)$ and $\mathcal{L}(x^p)=\frac{\Gamma(p+1)}{s^{p+1}}$ can be turned into
$$ \Gamma(p+1)\int_{0}^{+\infty}s^{-1-p}e^{-s}(1-\cos s)\,ds\qquad (\cos s=\text{Re}\,e^{is}) $$
hence it is enough to exploit the integral representation for the $\Gamma$ function together with its reflection formula.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer,it's really wonderful, but what should I do next?

Comment: I'm sorry to waste your time，but I still don't know what this inverse transformation does

Comment: @JamesJ: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis  together with  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function   and   http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html   solve your problem.

Comment: ♦ Thanks a lot for the links,I learned a lot of.